# Style Sheet sometimes does not load Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: theming, caching, css-js-aggregation

I am using the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module to load css once the page has loaded:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/advagg_css/css__fQOpwieSv5u9MLUdCJW8AX3ysBkVaiLC0mNO9bCuF8c__FLUdFFsRYhU7NN2T4QA7b0pMyQP1W1hRmVlZ5H2Saxs__sq6B6dIZCxhnK6op34i0_MkLadmDDYLWNc-Y9yWUjsQ.css" media="all" as="style" onload="window.advagg_mod_loadcss = function() {if (window.jQuery) {if (jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.holdReady)){jQuery.holdReady(false);}} else {setTimeout(advagg_mod_loadcss, 100);}};setTimeout(advagg_mod_loadcss, 200);this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

The problem is that sometimes only on Microsoft Edge, the stylesheet does not get loaded (I don't see the styles getting applied on my site).  Once I reload the page, it works fine.  It's hard to replicate because it does not happen all the time and it only happens one time per page.

I don't see any errors in the developer console.

When looking at the Network Tab it shows that it gets the file from cache.

[image]

I posted an issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/issues/3009746) on Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation issue queue.

I had an older version of Microsoft Edge (14) and I could not reproduce the problem. It looks like it only happens in version 17.

Comment: Is the snippet you posted custom code you've written yourself? Did you already check advaggs issue queue? As that probably is the place where this question belongs to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sounds like a bug report and should be posted on drupal.org instead.

Comment: @leymannx This is not custom code but how advagg works.  I did check and posted an issue on Advaggs module but did not get any feedback.

Comment: Cool, could you include the URL to the issue in your question?